# Discord.Js problems with sending a message to a specific channel

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have been editing my code and it worked fine until I changed the channel it sends the message in from the same channel the user sent a message in to a specified one. Tried looking for a few solutions, but I couldn`t really find any.

This is the parts of my code in question:

```
const exampleEmbed = {
      color: 0xff0000,
      title: '◄◄ ‼ help request ‼ ►►',
      fields: [
        { name: `user:`, value: `${msg.author}` },
        { name: 'reason:', value: msg.content.slice(3) || 'no reason specified', inline: true },
        { name: 'location:', value: msg, inline: true }
      ],
      timestamp: new Date().toISOString()
    };
    const row = new ActionRowBuilder()
            .addComponents(
                new ButtonBuilder()
                    .setCustomId('primary')
                    .setLabel('handled✅')
                    .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Primary),
            );

    const channel = client.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.id === StaffChannelID)

    message = await channel.send({ content : `<@&${StaffRoleID}>`, embeds: [ exampleEmbed ], components: [ row ] });
```

Comment: It's possible that the channel you wanted was not in the cache. Try using `const channel = await client.channels.fetch(channel => channel.id === StaffChannelID)`. Are you sure that the channel id is correct?

Comment: It fixed that problem, now it tells me that channel.send is not a function

Comment: it now gives me this error: Value "channel => channel.id === StaffChannelID" is not snowflake. And the channel id is indeed correct

Comment: `fetch()` takes an id, not a callback function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside of the embed that I send, I tried mentioning a specific message that is what caused this error. After removing it everything works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

I use `get` for my bot, I think it is easier, and it works.

```js
let channel = client.channels.cache.get(`${StaffChannelID}`)
```

If this **didn't** work, use:

```js
// if didn't work
let channel = client.channels.cache.get(StaffChannelID)
```

then send the message:

```js
if(channel){

let message = await channel.send({ content : `<@&${StaffRoleID}>`, embeds: [exampleEmbed], components: [row] });

} else{

return message.reply('There is no channel to send the help request to!');

}
```

Comment: Both dont work and I am still getting the `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded'` error

Comment: It seems that some function is called infinitely and that`s what causes the error. but I don`t think that channel.send is the one. I checked and it is the channel.send function that causes it to happen. Do you know why that is?

Comment: I use `channel.send` myself